# How to plot the graph of cos function for specific value of Pi in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

For a specific function,

`x(n) = A Cos(ωn+θ)` , for `ω = π/6` , and `θ = π/3`

I am unable to plot the graph.

For the general Cosine function, I can plot it using:

```
x = -pi:0.01:pi;
plot(x,cos(x))
```

But how to plot graph for specific pi values of omega and theta?

Comment: Please define "unable". Are you running into an error? Are you having a difficulty with substitution? Greek characters in MATLAB? Does the plot not look right? Start by computing the `x` values according to the equation you provided, using MATLAB's `pi` for `π`, and not skipping the `*` operator in `ωn`. Plotting is done exactly the way you wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than just defining your constants first...

```
w = pi/6;
th = pi/3;
A = 1;
```

Then plotting them?

```
n = -pi:0.01:pi;
plot(n, A*cos(w*n + th) );
```

Comment: bro, how to plot for discrete values instead of continuous values? is it ideal to ask another question?

Comment: @OBX modify the `n` vector to whatever you need, i.e. `pi*[0.5 1 3]`.

Comment: To elaborate on what @Dev-iL says, `-pi:0.01:pi` is just a way of creating a vector, listing it manually will do the same `[0.1, pi, 1.5432]` etc. To plot these as points (instead of points connected by a line, as is default) use `plot(x, y, '.')`